# Java executing C application with arguments and get back the return value?

Tags: java, c

Hi i am trying to build a java program but i need run a C program with arguments and after i need get the return value..

Here is what i have done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pr = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\MyFolder\\Desktop\\MyExe.exe", "param1", "param2");
    Process process = pr.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
int retVal = process.waitFor()
```

to block execution until the process is finished, and returns the return value.

See the docs for `Process` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()